# Weird Message from JQuery - Assuming it wasn't found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some HTML like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"> Carousel </label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select class="form-control carouselUser" name="aisis_options[carousel]">
            <option value="Please Select a Role">Please Select a Role</option>
            <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
            <option value="Editor">Editor</option><option value="Author">Author</option> 
            <option value="Contributor">Contributor</option>
            <option value="Subscriber">Subscriber</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I then attempted to do something like this:

```
$('.carouselGlobal').change(function(){
    console.log($('.form_group .col-sm-5 .carouselUser'));
    $('.form_group .col-sm-5 .carouselUser').hide();
});
```

I'm more interested in the `console.log()` which spits out:

```
[prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: ".form_group .col-sm-5 .carouselUser", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]
```

I have no idea what this means so I assume that it can't find the object in question.

**What are you trying to do?**

Some where on the page is that piece of HTML I showed you, when the `.carouselGlobal` changed it (the piece of HTML) needs to hide.

**Problem?**

I get that weird message in the console, which I assumes is jquery saying "I cannot find object bla".

So what am I doing wrong? From what I thought, this was right ....

Even doing something like:

```
$('.carouselGlobal').change(function(){
    console.log($('.carouselUser').parent('.form_group'));
    $('.carouselUser').parent('.form_group').hide();
});
```

Doesn't work ...

Comment: Where is .carouselGlobal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'strange' output you are seeing in the console is the jQuery object itself being serialised. This object is *always* returned whether or not the selector you use finds any elements.

If you want to discover if there are any elements found, use the `length` property:

```
$('.carouselGlobal').change(function(){
    console.log($('.form_group .col-sm-5 .carouselUser').length); // 0 = not found
    $('.form_group .col-sm-5 .carouselUser').hide();
});
```

If there is specific information you want to see about the element, you just need to amend your `console.log` to show it.